# Mysql count two rows in single query

Tags: mysql, count

Is it possible to count two rows in a single query? Right now i'm using two queries:

```
SELECT count(draft) AS draftCount FROM projects WHERE draft = 1 AND user_id = ?
```

And another one:

```
SELECT count(published) AS publishedCount FROM projects WHERE published = 1 AND user_id = ?
```

I would like to combine those two queries into one is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(published) AS publishedCount,
       SUM(draft) AS draftCount
FROM projects
WHERE user_id = ?
```

As far as I understood your query the values of `published` and `draft` are `1` for true and `0` for false. So you can just `SUM` them to get the same result.

Comment: This response is much more concise than the alternative

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT count(case when draft = 1 then draft end) AS draftCount,
count(case when published = 1 then published end) AS publishedCount 
FROM projects 
WHERE user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION:

```
(SELECT count(draft) FROM projects WHERE draft = 1 AND user_id = 4)
UNION
(SELECT count(published) FROM projects WHERE published = 1 AND user_id = 4);
```